# GPO: What's the scope of "Specify startup policy processing wait time"?

Tags: group-policy

Set on some GPO, the value of "***Specify startup policy processing wait time***" is **System-wide** or **GPO-specific** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is system-wide, not gpo-specific.

Take a look at "Always wait for the network at computer startup and logon" in `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Logon` too if you want the computer to wait for the network.

Answer (score -1):

"Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\System\Group Policy\Specify startup policy processing wait time"